# React JS: Two Filters on the same JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, filter

**Summary Problem**
I have two inputs that I am trying to filter data for:

1. Filtering for videoTitle and teacherName
2. Filtering for tags (nested array in JSON)

I cannot get the `tag` filter to work. It currently doesn't seem to filter the JSON at all and just returns all the data.

**Context**
Currently have the data being fetched and filtering successfully on the first filter (videoTitle & teacherName).

Environment: MacOS 11.2.3, React 17.0.1, VSCode

**What have I tried?**
Getting visibility on the conditional to see what's being returned. It seems the conditional is filtering through the tags array but the return is not working.

**Code**

Fetching Data and mapping

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    error: false,
    searchQuery: "",
    tagQuery: "",
    results: [],
    loadingData: false,
  }

  getInfo = () => {
    this.setState({ loadingData: true })
    axios.get('https://**********')
    .then(({ data }) => {
      data.sort((a, b) => b.averageUserRating - a.averageUserRating);
        this.setState({ results: data });
        this.setState({ loadingData: false })
    })
    .catch(() => this.setState({ error: true }))
  }
```

2x Change Handlers (One for each input)

```
  handleSearchInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      searchQuery: this.search.value
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.searchQuery && this.state.searchQuery.length > 1) {
        if (this.state.searchQuery.length % 2 === 0) {
          this.getInfo()
        }
      } else if (this.state.searchQuery === "") {
          this.setState({ results: [] })
      }
    })
  }

  handleTagInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      tagQuery: this.tag.value
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.tagQuery && this.state.tagQuery.length > 1) {
        if (this.state.tagQuery.length % 2 === 0) {
          this.getInfo()
        }
      } else if (this.state.tagQuery === "") {
          this.setState({ results: [] })
      }
    })
  }
```

**The Render method**

```
render() {

    const searchForTutorials = this.state.results.filter((data) => {
      if (this.state.searchQuery == null)
        return data;
      else if (data.videoTitle.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) || data.teacherName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
        return data;
      }
    }).map(data => {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li style={{position:'relative', left: '10vh'}}>
              <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.videoTitle}</span>
              <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.videoUrl}</span>
              <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.teacherName}</span>
              <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.tags.map(word => word)}</span>
              {/* <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.averageUserRating}</span> */}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    })

    const searchForTags = this.state.results.filter((data) => {
      if (this.state.tagQuery == null)
        return data;
      else if (data.tags.map(word => word.toLowerCase()).includes(this.state.tagQuery.toLowerCase())) {
        return data;
      }
    }).map(data => {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li style={{position:'relative', left: '10vh'}}>
              <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.videoTitle}</span>
              <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.videoUrl}</span>
              <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.teacherName}</span>
              <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.tags.map(word => word)}</span>
              {/* <span style={{paddingRight:'10px'}}>{data.averageUserRating}</span> */}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search for Tutorials..."
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          onChange={this.handleSearchInputChange}
          />

          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search using Tags..."
            ref={input => this.tag = input}
            onChange={this.handleTagInputChange}
          />

          {this.state.loadingData && <button>Loading...</button>}
          {!this.state.loadingData &&
          <button 
            type="button" 
            onClick={() => this.getInfo() }>
            <span>Refresh Data</span>
      </button>}
          {searchForTutorials}
          {searchForTags}
      </form>

    )
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: There are too many details not related to the question itself.

If you remove unnecessary details, it'll be much easier to help you.

Comment: Your condition to filter results doesn't work well: `'' == null // false`. It's never true in your code, so, why do you have it there?

Comment: Also, you're rendering results content twice, which doesn't look right. To fix it, you need to chain filter calls and render results once.

Comment: I'm relatively new to React and wasn't sure how to render the data for the two different inputs, so this is my work around until I can figure that out.

Thank you for the tip on chaining filter calls.

Answer (score 0):

In the `searchForTags` filter method, the second if:

```js
else if (data.tags.map(word => word.toLowerCase()).includes(this.state.tagQuery.toLowerCase())) {
```

I am not sure if you intention here but you are returning and array of boolean `[true, false, true, ...]` value which evaluates always to true. You should use run [some function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) over the mapped values in order to find if you have any related tag

E.g.:

```js
const searchForTags = this.state.results.filter((data) => {
  if (this.state.tagQuery === null) {
    return true;
  }
  return data.tags
    .map(word => word.toLowerCase())
    .some(word => word === this.state.tagQuery.toLowerCase()); // stops at the first match found and return true
}
```

Remember that when you are using `Array.filter` your function should return a boolean in order to keep it or discard from the filtering.

Comment: Tomeu, thank you. That makes a lot of sense. I'm going to try it out now.

Comment: It looks as if my return function is returning `true` for everything (even with Tomeu's code). Meaning anything typed into the `tagQuery` input returns ALL the data.

Comment: As a general advice for this kind of problem, I would suggest to check what is returning your filtering function. Check if manually hardcoding `tagQuery` with known values does the job and start from there

Comment: @timcastillogill, it might be the case that all the data is rendered from `searchForTutorials `,

Comment: `searchForTutorials` returns a filtered table according to `videoTitle` or `teacherName` which is why I was thinking it is the way in which I'm mapping through the tags to filter.